# Colorschemes when entering a buffer

Tags: colors, buffer, vim

I have this in my ***.vimrc***:

```
augroup filetype_colorscheme
        au BufEnter *
        \ if !exists('b:colors_name')
            \ | if &ft == "vim"
                \ | let b:colors_name = 'color_dark'
            \ | else
                \ | let b:colors_name = 'color_light'
            \ | endif
        \ | endif
        \ | exe 'colorscheme' b:colors_name
augroup END
```

*What it does*:
When I open a **.vim page** it opens my **dark colorscheme** "color_dark.vim"
when I open whatever **other page** it opens my **light colorscheme** "color_light.vim"

This is very nice but it is not so nice in split windows.
Every time when I click in a split window with p.e. a text file, all split windows become light colored with the light colorscheme (even the .vim files).
When I switch to a vim file in a split window all other files in the other split windows become dark as well.

Is it possible to retain every filetype his own colorscheme in a split window?
What do I have to change in above code?

**EDIT**
If this is not possible would it be possible to disable above code when I enter in a split window? (in order to let me choose the colorscheme myself, the same for all split windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colorschemes will always affect the entire vim instance.  It is not possible to have a different color scheme per split window.

Edit 1: To answer your second question in the edit, you can probably add `&& winnr('$') == 1` to that first `if` to stop this from happening when you have multiple split windows open.

Edit 2: Whoops, the edit above would not work, however I think wrapping everything in another `if` should.

Edit 3: Missed a couple of pipes.

```
augroup filetype_colorscheme
        au BufEnter *
        \ | if winnr('$') == 1
                \ if !exists('b:colors_name')
                    \ | if &ft == "vim"
                        \ | let b:colors_name = 'color_dark'
                    \ | else
                        \ | let b:colors_name = 'color_light'
                    \ | endif
                \ | endif
                \ | exe 'colorscheme' b:colors_name
        \ | endif
augroup END
```

Comment: Commenting in case editing an answer doesn't trigger a notification for you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with your last comment, can you please explain it a bit more? Btw.. I added your code to the first if, it gives an error: Undefined variable: b:colors_name

Comment: Thanks Randy. I still receive an error :-(  --> Error detected while processing BufEnter Auto commands for "*":
E15: Invalid expression: winnr('$'} == 1

Comment: You have a `}` instead of an `)` in your call to `winnr()`.

Comment: No I wish I had. I did write it wrong in my comment, sorry. I copied the code in your answer. The error is still there. Did you check it in your own .vimrc?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10333/discussion-between-randy-morris-and-remonn)